# How to exclude default creation of route tables & its routes while creating VPC using the AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc

I'm curious to know if we can exclude the default creation of any resources using L2 construct,
specifically route tables & its routes. I want to explicitly create only two public & private route tables & its routes after that reference them in ec2.Vpc construct so it won't create on its own.

I have tried to explicitly write route tables & its routes using L1 constructs but faced blocker when I had to reference them to `ec2.Vpc` construct.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/4308

Comment: As per reference, can i remove all auto created route tables & its routes then try to explicitly defining route tables using L1 constructs & attach it to VPC created by L2 construct ec2.vpc ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. See https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/5927 for umbrella feature request. If you don't find what you need, you might consider building your own VPC construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options if the public L2 APIs aren't enough:

1. **Additive approach**:  Build from scratch using L1 constructs.  If you get stuck, take a look at the [CDK source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/6e4b4eab65dacea52af7d955575887bbafdff1fc/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-ec2/lib/vpc.ts#L1130). You can often reverse engineer what you need by looking at how the CDK does it.
2. **Subtractive approach**:  Start with the L2.  Use [escape hatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html#cfn_layer_resource) syntax to [modify](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.CfnResource.html#addwbrpropertywbroverridepropertypath-value) (`node.findChild` and `addPropertyOverride`) or [delete](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/constructs.Node.html#trywbrremovewbrchildchildnamespan-classapi-icon-api-icon-experimental-titlethis-api-element-is-experimental-it-may-change-without-noticespan) (`node.tryRemoveChild`) child constructs.